# Scala Lists of lists of integers

Tags: list, scala

I am new to Scala and am a bit confused.

Given a list of lists `List[List[Int]]`, how can one call a specific index of an element of each list, for example the second element of each list?

Answer (score 9):

Simple:

```
val ints = List( List(1,2), List(3,4) )
val result = ints.map( l => l(1) )
```

This will produce `(2,4)`.

Answer (score 6):

While both of the other answers work, here is another version that is both safe to use and not complex. You can `lift` a `Seq` to a `Function[Int, Option[A]]` to make `apply` return `Option`s instead of throwing exceptions. In Addition you can use `flatMap` instead of `map{...}.flatten`

```
List(List(1), List(1,2), List(1,2,3)).flatMap { xs =>
  xs.lift(1)
}

// res1: List[Int] = List(2, 2)
```